# How to eliminate this space?

Tags: lists

[image][image]

I want the text ocupating this space like the first image, please see the image

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=4cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\author{J.Leonardo}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\item
\item
\item \textbf{Método de Newton-Raphson}\\
Sea la misma función del problema anterior\\
\\$f(x) = 2exp(x) -x^{2} -8x + 4, x \in [1,3] $
%\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[a)] 
\item  Muestre que la gráfica de la función $f(x)$  es cóncava hacia arriba 
en el intervalo $[1,3]$ , demuestre por concavidad que $f(x)$ posee a lo mas 
dos soluciones en el intervalo $[1,3]$ . Use el teorema de Bolzano para 
probar que existe una única solución en el intervalo $[1,2]$ y una única 
solución en el intervalo $[2,3]$ .¿Coincide esto con lo obtenido en el 
problema anterior? Muestre geométricamente que la concavidad del intervalo 
$[1,3]$ garantiza la convergencia del método de Newton-Raphson para los 
puntos iniciales $x_0=1$ y $x_0=3$ .Implemente un algoritmo en Matlab que 
permita visualizar la gráfica de la funcion $f(x)$ en el intervalo dado. 
Muestre el algoritmo y la gráfica obtenida.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  However, your question is posed in an unacceptable format.  You are expected to post code, rather than a picture of code.  The code should be a minimum possible example that demonstrates the errant or broken behavior.  You should edit your question to provide the readers with useful information.

Comment: That looks like a enumerated list of some sort and that spcing/indenting is expected for such a list. You give no code you we can't tell what you are doing.

Comment: Please I currently add the code please Can you help me?

Comment: You can comment out the line `\usepackage{enumerate}` and see if you prefer the default layout of numbered lists. `\usepackage{enumerate}` changes the default layout, so every item text will be indented at the right edge of the number label.

Comment: Hi, I want the text like the first image, but I get the second image when I compile please help me

Comment: I currently edit again the images please check it

Comment: @JEANLEONARDO if you look at your first image closely, you will notice that the space between “b)” and “Implemente” is different from the space between “c)” and “Implemente”. This should give you a clue that the original is not a list, but simply a typed paragraph. That is, the original author typed `b) Implemente ... <blank line> c) Implemente ... <blank line> d) ...`

Comment: Is there a package that does lists with counting, but not the majority of the list fortmatting?

Comment: Use `\exp`, not `exp` in math.  As for `$x_0=1$ y $x_0=3$`, I'm glad I don't read math in Spanish.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using the `enumerate` package, I propose the `enumitem` package.  Don A. points out in a comment that my original approach was approximate, and that a correct approach would be to specify the label of the inner enumeration as

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph{*}),leftmargin=0pt,labelwidth=14pt,
  labelsep=4pt,itemindent=18pt,align=left]
```

Thank you, Don.  The MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}%\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=4cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\author{J.Leonardo}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\item
\item
\item \textbf{Método de Newton-Raphson}\\
Sea la misma función del problema anterior\\
\\$f(x) = 2\exp(x) -x^{2} -8x + 4, x \in [1,3] $
%\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph{*}),leftmargin=0pt,labelwidth=14pt,
  labelsep=4pt,itemindent=18pt,align=left] 
\item  Muestre que la gráfica de la función $f(x)$  es cóncava hacia arriba 
en el intervalo $[1,3]$, demuestre por concavidad que $f(x)$ posee a lo mas 
dos soluciones en el intervalo $[1,3]$ . Use el teorema de Bolzano para 
probar que existe una única solución en el intervalo $[1,2]$ y una única 
solución en el intervalo $[2,3]$ .¿Coincide esto con lo obtenido en el 
problema anterior? Muestre geométricamente que la concavidad del intervalo 
$[1,3]$ garantiza la convergencia del método de Newton-Raphson para los 
puntos iniciales $x_0=1$ y $x_0=3$. Implemente un algoritmo en Matlab que 
permita visualizar la gráfica de la funcion $f(x)$ en el intervalo dado. 
Muestre el algoritmo y la gráfica obtenida.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works...And how you figure out the problem? Awesome

Comment: @JEANLEONARDO I have found the `enumitem` package useful for making lists.  You can access the documentation through here: https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem

Comment: +1. Even easier than `leftmargin=0pt,itemindent=15pt` is `wide=0pt`.

Comment: Uh no. You can see the label sticks into the margin a little bit, which will be more for item "m)". Package enumitem is fine, but doesn't really change the odd way LaTeX positions its item labels. You need left aligned labels and widths and spaces that add up to exactly hit the margin. `[label=\alph{*}),leftmargin=0pt,labelwidth=14pt,labelsep=4pt,itemindent=18pt,align=left]` where 14+4 = 18.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau Thank you for exacting out what was clearly an approximation on my part.

Comment: There is a missing \exp in mathmode :-) like the original MWE.

Comment: Thank you @Sebastiano. Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

`enumitem`, as explained by @Mico in a comment, provides an option to format the list as you want:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*), wide=0pt]
```

Don't attempt to guess explicit values by hand, because `enumitem` has tool to compute the list parameters based on the contents of the label.